# Excel formula in VBA code with references to a table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm desperately trying to enter via vba this formula into Excel cell:

```
=Fontevrault!R165+SUMIFS(Liste1[MONTANT PAYÉ PAR CONTINGENCE],Liste1[DÉCOMPTE],CONCATENATE("Décompte ",1),Liste1[ITEM AU BORDEREAU / AUTRE],"AUTRE - Justifier",Liste1[TRONÇON],"Fontevrault").
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sheets("D" & Format(iprog, "00")).Cells(i + 1, 8).Formula = "='" & Sheets("Info").Cells(itroncon, 2).Value & "'!R" & ligneTotBord & "+SUMIFS(Liste1[MONTANT PAYÉ PAR CONTINGENCE],Liste1[DÉCOMPTE],CONCATENATE(""Décompte ""," & iprog & "),Liste1[ITEM AU BORDEREAU / AUTRE],""AUTRE - Justifier"",Liste1[TRONÇON],""" & Sheets("Info").Cells(itroncon, 2).Value & ""
```

I always end up with this error.

[image]

I've tried to identify the source of the problem for the past couple of hours, but nothing.

If someone know the reason, please let me know.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis. There may be other issues. Using `Debug.Print` here and inspecting the output in the Immediate Window should help spot any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
Sheets("D" & Format(iprog, "00")).Cells(i + 1, 8).Formula = "='" & Sheets("Info").Cells(itroncon, 2).Value & "'!R" & ligneTotBord & "+SUMIFS(Liste1[MONTANT PAYÉ PAR CONTINGENCE],Liste1[DÉCOMPTE],CONCATENATE(""Décompte ""," & iprog & "),Liste1[ITEM AU BORDEREAU / AUTRE],""AUTRE - Justifier"",Liste1[TRONÇON],""" & Sheets("Info").Cells(itroncon, 2).Value & """)"
```

For your information, the problem was the name of my table header, I wrote:

"MONTANT

PAYÉ PAR

CONTINGENCE"

in the header of my table (with return between each line). Once I removed those return, it works.